# what is <p>{{"TABLE.TRANSACTION_NUMBER"| translate}}</p> in angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn angular and is new to it. While going through some code I came across some lines and could not understand them, also tried to search them but could not find any explanation.
Can anyone explain or give me links from where I can understand what these kinds of lines actually do?

```
<div class="title-container">
          <p>{{"TABLE.DATE_TIME"| translate}}</p>
          <p>{{"TABLE.TRANSACTION_NUMBER"| translate}}</p>
          <p>{{"TABLE.FROM"| translate}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the answer provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is the curly braces `{{}}`, used for displaying data. Curly braces allow you to bind objects from the component.ts to the template (html).

Read more on angular tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

The second part is the `|` pipe, this is to take the data and transform it to present in a different way on the screen. A pipe will take the data (left side of the pipe) as input and returns the transformed form of it based on the type of pipe (right side of the `|`.

Read more here: 
https://angular.io/guide/pipes